Bistable Multivibrator circuit not working

In the above image, there is a bistable multivibrator circuit in Figure 1. The output of stage 1 of this circuit at \$V_{o1} \$ is supposed to be a square wave with a peak to peak voltage of 15 V with zero average and a frequency of 10 kHz or 0.1 ms period.
The output is not working correctly. The input to this bistable multivibrator at \$V_-\$ terminal of Op amp \$U_2\$ from \$V_{c1}\$ is a supposed to be triangular wave with a peak to peak voltage of 7.5 V and frequency of 10 kHz or 0.1 ms period.
\$V_{TH}\$ and \$V_{TL}\$ of the bistable multivibrator in Figure 1 are 3.75 V and -3.75 V at which the output of \$V_{o1}\$ is supposed to change state. The output at \$V_{o2}\$ is supposed to be a triangular wave with a peak to peak voltage of 15 V and 0.1 ms period. Op amp saturation voltages are at +13 V and -13 V.
I separated the circuit as Figure 2 and Figure 3 with their inputs and resistors as per the calculations. I don't get any output for Figure 2 at \$V_{o3}\$ as in Figure 1 at \$V_{o1}\$. The original circuit in Figure 1 has GND connected to resistor \$R_6\$. I tried giving a pulse of 1 ms period and 1 ms on time with a 1 V amplitude to make any oscillations happen, but it's not working.
What is the reason for this circuit to not function as expected? What modifications can you suggest to get square waves and triangular waves at \$V_{o1}\$ and \$V_{o2}\$ ?
Your responses are appreciated.
LTspice .asc file for the circuit is below:
Version 4
SHEET 1 2068 1620
WIRE 672 16 624 16
WIRE 880 16 752 16
WIRE -288 144 -336 144
WIRE 0 144 -208 144
WIRE 368 144 112 144
WIRE 624 144 624 16
WIRE 624 144 448 144
WIRE 672 144 624 144
WIRE 1120 144 1104 144
WIRE 880 160 880 16
WIRE 880 160 736 160
WIRE 1008 160 880 160
WIRE 672 176 624 176
WIRE 704 208 704 192
WIRE 112 224 112 144
WIRE -592 272 -848 272
WIRE -336 272 -336 144
WIRE -336 272 -512 272
WIRE -288 272 -336 272
WIRE -160 288 -224 288
WIRE 0 288 0 144
WIRE 0 288 -80 288
WIRE 368 288 0 288
WIRE 560 288 448 288
WIRE 624 288 624 176
WIRE 624 288 560 288
WIRE 640 288 624 288
WIRE 704 288 640 288
WIRE 880 288 880 160
WIRE 880 288 784 288
WIRE -288 304 -336 304
WIRE -256 336 -256 320
WIRE 0 336 0 288
WIRE -848 352 -848 272
WIRE 624 368 624 288
WIRE 0 432 0 400
WIRE -1088 464 -1088 416
WIRE 624 464 624 432
WIRE 0 512 0 496
WIRE -1088 592 -1088 544
WIRE -992 592 -1088 592
WIRE -336 608 -336 304
WIRE 560 608 560 288
WIRE 560 608 -336 608
WIRE -992 624 -992 592
WIRE -1088 640 -1088 592
WIRE 800 688 752 688
WIRE 1008 688 880 688
WIRE -384 752 -432 752
WIRE -96 752 -304 752
WIRE -1088 768 -1088 720
WIRE 496 816 240 816
WIRE 752 816 752 688
WIRE 752 816 576 816
WIRE 800 816 752 816
WIRE 1008 832 1008 688
WIRE 1008 832 864 832
WIRE 1040 832 1008 832
WIRE 1216 832 1200 832
WIRE 800 848 752 848
WIRE -688 880 -944 880
WIRE -432 880 -432 752
WIRE -432 880 -608 880
WIRE -384 880 -432 880
WIRE 832 880 832 864
WIRE -256 896 -320 896
WIRE -96 896 -96 752
WIRE -96 896 -176 896
WIRE -48 896 -96 896
WIRE -16 896 -48 896
WIRE 240 896 240 816
WIRE -944 912 -944 880
WIRE -384 912 -432 912
WIRE -352 944 -352 928
WIRE -96 944 -96 896
WIRE 496 960 240 960
WIRE 752 960 752 848
WIRE 752 960 576 960
WIRE 832 960 752 960
WIRE 1008 960 1008 832
WIRE 1008 960 912 960
WIRE 240 1024 240 960
WIRE -944 1040 -944 992
WIRE -96 1040 -96 1008
WIRE 752 1040 752 960
WIRE -96 1120 -96 1104
WIRE -432 1136 -432 912
WIRE 752 1136 752 1104
WIRE 240 1152 240 1104
WIRE -432 1312 -432 1216
FLAG -992 624 0
FLAG -1088 768 Vee
FLAG -1088 416 Vcc
FLAG 704 208 Vee
FLAG 704 128 Vcc
FLAG 112 224 0
FLAG 624 464 0
FLAG -256 336 Vee
FLAG -256 256 Vcc
FLAG 0 512 0
FLAG 832 880 Vee
FLAG 832 800 Vcc
FLAG 240 896 0
FLAG 752 1136 0
FLAG -352 944 Vee
FLAG -352 864 Vcc
FLAG -96 1120 0
FLAG -432 1312 0
FLAG 0 288 Vo1
FLAG -944 1040 0
FLAG 240 1152 0
FLAG -848 352 0
FLAG 752 960 Vc2
FLAG 640 288 Vc1
FLAG 1008 160 Vo2
FLAG -48 896 Vo3
FLAG 1040 832 Vo4
SYMBOL voltage -1088 448 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 13
SYMBOL voltage -1088 624 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value 13
SYMBOL res 768 0 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res 464 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL res 800 272 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL cap 608 368 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 0.5nF
SYMBOL res 464 272 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res -192 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res -496 256 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL res -64 272 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 5.2012k
SYMBOL zener 16 400 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value PTZ6_8B
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL zener -16 432 R0
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value PTZ6_8B
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL res 896 672 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res 592 800 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL res 928 944 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R10
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL cap 736 1040 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 0.5nF
SYMBOL res 592 944 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R11
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL voltage 240 1008 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value PULSE(-7.5 7.5 0 0 0 0.00005 0.0001)
SYMBOL OpAmps\\OP296 -256 352 M180
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMBOL OpAmps\\OP296 704 96 R0
SYMATTR InstName U4
SYMBOL res -288 736 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R12
SYMATTR Value 100K
SYMBOL res -592 864 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R13
SYMATTR Value 100K
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL res -160 880 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R14
SYMATTR Value 5.3012k
SYMBOL zener -80 1008 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMATTR Value PTZ6_8B
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL zener -112 1040 R0
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMATTR Value PTZ6_8B
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL OpAmps\\OP296 -352 960 M180
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL voltage -432 1120 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(-3.75 3.75 0 0.00005 0.00005 0 0.0001)
SYMBOL voltage -944 896 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V5
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 1 0 0 0 1m 1m)
SYMBOL OpAmps\\OP296 832 768 R0
SYMATTR InstName U3
TEXT -788 1256 Left 2 !.tran 1m
TEXT -1088 1360 Left 2 ;Descrption: Bistable multivibrator circuit\nVersion: 0.1
TEXT 24 664 Left 2 ;Figure 1
TEXT -464 1384 Left 2 ;Figure 2
TEXT 584 1256 Left 2 ;Figure 3

Edit:
After correcting the power supplies for first stage in Figure 1 and changing the OP amp, the following waveforms are obtained For this application, an op amp with higher bandwidth is required. LT1056 seems to fit it exactly. Op296 op amp seemed to make the circuit in an indeterminate state. The only problem was that Voltage at \$V_{o1}\$ had about 8 V peak This is due to higher forward voltage drop of the zener diodes used. I had used a 6.8 V zener from ROHM with the model PTZ6_8B. The output signal had a frequency of about 9 KHz.This is mainly due to some errors in calculating \$V_{TH}\$ and \$V_{TL}\$ for the multivibrator exactly. Something can be done to change the frequency to near 10 KHz.
LTspice asc file for the circuit is below:
Version 4
SHEET 1 2068 1620
WIRE 672 16 624 16
WIRE 880 16 752 16
WIRE -1088 144 -1088 96
WIRE -288 144 -336 144
WIRE 0 144 -208 144
WIRE 368 144 112 144
WIRE 624 144 624 16
WIRE 624 144 448 144
WIRE 672 144 624 144
WIRE 1120 144 1104 144
WIRE 880 160 880 16
WIRE 880 160 736 160
WIRE 1008 160 880 160
WIRE 672 176 624 176
WIRE 704 208 704 192
WIRE 112 224 112 144
WIRE -1088 272 -1088 224
WIRE -992 272 -1088 272
WIRE -592 272 -848 272
WIRE -336 272 -336 144
WIRE -336 272 -512 272
WIRE -288 272 -336 272
WIRE -160 288 -224 288
WIRE 0 288 0 144
WIRE 0 288 -80 288
WIRE 368 288 0 288
WIRE 560 288 448 288
WIRE 624 288 624 176
WIRE 624 288 560 288
WIRE 640 288 624 288
WIRE 704 288 640 288
WIRE 880 288 880 160
WIRE 880 288 784 288
WIRE -992 304 -992 272
WIRE -288 304 -336 304
WIRE -1088 320 -1088 272
WIRE -256 336 -256 320
WIRE 0 336 0 288
WIRE -848 352 -848 272
WIRE 624 368 624 288
WIRE 0 432 0 400
WIRE -1088 448 -1088 400
WIRE 624 464 624 432
WIRE 0 512 0 496
WIRE -336 608 -336 304
WIRE 560 608 560 288
WIRE 560 608 -336 608
WIRE 864 736 816 736
WIRE 1072 736 944 736
WIRE -384 752 -432 752
WIRE -96 752 -304 752
WIRE 1216 832 1200 832
WIRE 560 864 304 864
WIRE 816 864 816 736
WIRE 816 864 640 864
WIRE 864 864 816 864
WIRE -688 880 -944 880
WIRE -432 880 -432 752
WIRE -432 880 -608 880
WIRE -384 880 -432 880
WIRE 1072 880 1072 736
WIRE 1072 880 928 880
WIRE 1104 880 1072 880
WIRE -256 896 -320 896
WIRE -96 896 -96 752
WIRE -96 896 -176 896
WIRE -48 896 -96 896
WIRE -16 896 -48 896
WIRE 864 896 816 896
WIRE -384 912 -432 912
WIRE 896 928 896 912
WIRE -352 944 -352 928
WIRE -96 944 -96 896
WIRE 304 944 304 864
WIRE 560 1008 304 1008
WIRE 816 1008 816 896
WIRE 816 1008 640 1008
WIRE 896 1008 816 1008
WIRE 1072 1008 1072 880
WIRE 1072 1008 976 1008
WIRE -944 1040 -944 880
WIRE -96 1040 -96 1008
WIRE 304 1072 304 1008
WIRE 816 1088 816 1008
WIRE -96 1120 -96 1104
WIRE -432 1136 -432 912
WIRE 816 1184 816 1152
WIRE 304 1200 304 1152
WIRE -432 1312 -432 1216
FLAG -992 304 0
FLAG -1088 448 Vee
FLAG -1088 96 Vcc
FLAG 704 208 Vee
FLAG 704 128 Vcc
FLAG 112 224 0
FLAG 624 464 0
FLAG 0 512 0
FLAG 896 928 Vee
FLAG 896 848 Vcc
FLAG 304 944 0
FLAG 816 1184 0
FLAG -96 1120 0
FLAG -432 1312 0
FLAG 0 288 Vo1
FLAG -944 1040 0
FLAG 304 1200 0
FLAG -848 352 0
FLAG 816 1008 Vc2
FLAG 640 288 Vc1
FLAG 1008 160 Vo2
FLAG -48 896 Vo3
FLAG 1104 880 Vo4
FLAG -256 336 Vcc
FLAG -256 256 Vee
FLAG -352 944 Vcc
FLAG -352 864 Vee
SYMBOL voltage -1088 128 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 13
SYMBOL voltage -1088 304 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value 13
SYMBOL res 768 0 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res 464 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL res 800 272 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL cap 608 368 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 0.5nF
SYMBOL res 464 272 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res -192 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res -496 256 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL res -64 272 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 5.2012k
SYMBOL zener 16 400 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value PTZ6_8B
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL zener -16 432 R0
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value PTZ6_8B
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL res 960 720 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res 656 848 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL res 992 992 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R10
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL cap 800 1088 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 0.5nF
SYMBOL res 656 992 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R11
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL voltage 304 1056 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value PULSE(-7.5 7.5 0 0 0 0.00005 0.0001)
SYMBOL res -288 736 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R12
SYMATTR Value 100K
SYMBOL res -592 864 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R13
SYMATTR Value 100K
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL res -160 880 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R14
SYMATTR Value 5.3012k
SYMBOL zener -80 1008 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMATTR Value PTZ6_8B
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL zener -112 1040 R0
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMATTR Value PTZ6_8B
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL voltage -432 1120 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(-3.75 3.75 0 0.00005 0.00005 0 0.0001)
SYMBOL OpAmps\\LT1056 896 816 R0
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMBOL OpAmps\\LT1056 704 96 R0
SYMATTR InstName U5
SYMBOL OpAmps\\LT1056 -256 352 M180
SYMATTR InstName U6
SYMBOL OpAmps\\LT1056 -352 960 M180
SYMATTR InstName U7
TEXT -788 1256 Left 2 !.tran 1m
TEXT -1088 1360 Left 2 ;Descrption: Bistable multivibrator circuit\nVersion: 0.1
TEXT 24 664 Left 2 ;Figure 1
TEXT -464 1384 Left 2 ;Figure 2
TEXT 584 1256 Left 2 ;Figure 3

Reference:
Microelectronic circuits, 7e, Sedra and Smith, OUP India, year 2017, page 1117

What happens if you remove R4?

I removed $R_4$ equivalent $R_{10} $ in Figure 3, the gain of the second stage has increased. the output voltage at $ V_{o4}$ is about +8V to -5V approximately. There is no change in Figure 1 for removing $R_4$. There is only a DC voltage at $ V_{o4}$.

Removing R4 should enable the oscillation and removing R2 then should enable the square wave output of Vo2.

If $R_6$is much lowe as 10 KΩ,  then β of the multivibrator would change and that would also change change $V_{TL}$ and $V_{TH}$ , as a result, the rectangular wave might have different on time and off times.

Changed $R_6$ to 10KΩ  and removed $R_4$ in figure 1 , still no results at $V_{o1}$ and $V_{o2} $, just DC voltages.

I think the voltage divider R2/R1 defines a threshold that cannot be reached at the output Vo1 and the current trough R4 will prohibit oscillation, but I should test this theory in a simulator.

The ration R2/R1 in a hypothetical bistable multivibrator defines thresholds VTL and VTH. These define when the output can be HIGH or LOW as per Op amp saturation voltages. Since. the multivibtrator has a negative transfer characteristic, at input voltages below VTL, the output is high and input voltages above VTH, the output is low. The output level is limited by the zener diodes which s set at 7.5V in Figure 1  assuming zeners at 6.8 V reverse bias voltage and a 0.7 V forward voltage drop.

You call it a bistable, but it looks like it's an astable? Is that just a terminology mistake or am I missing something here?

I think the astable multivibrator used a bistable multivibrator. My error was in the bistable part.

Here you have the working version:


As you can see I change the opamp type LT1056.
And correct a small mistake you made in connecting the supply voltage to U2 (U1 on my schematic).
LTspice .asc file for the circuit is below:
Version 4
SHEET 1 2068 1620
WIRE 608 16 528 16
WIRE 784 16 688 16
WIRE -32 144 -144 144
WIRE 192 144 48 144
WIRE 384 144 320 144
WIRE 528 144 528 16
WIRE 528 144 464 144
WIRE 576 144 528 144
WIRE 784 160 784 16
WIRE 784 160 640 160
WIRE 912 160 784 160
WIRE 576 176 528 176
WIRE 608 208 608 192
WIRE -64 256 -64 240
WIRE -288 272 -320 272
WIRE -144 272 -144 144
WIRE -144 272 -208 272
WIRE -96 272 -144 272
WIRE 48 288 -32 288
WIRE 192 288 192 144
WIRE 192 288 128 288
WIRE 272 288 192 288
WIRE 464 288 352 288
WIRE 496 288 464 288
WIRE 528 288 528 176
WIRE 528 288 496 288
WIRE 608 288 528 288
WIRE 784 288 784 160
WIRE 784 288 688 288
WIRE -96 304 -144 304
WIRE -496 320 -496 272
WIRE 192 336 192 288
WIRE 528 368 528 288
WIRE 192 432 192 400
WIRE -496 448 -496 400
WIRE -400 448 -496 448
WIRE 528 464 528 432
WIRE -400 480 -400 448
WIRE -496 496 -496 448
WIRE 192 512 192 496
WIRE -144 608 -144 304
WIRE 464 608 464 288
WIRE 464 608 -144 608
WIRE -496 624 -496 576
FLAG -400 480 0
FLAG -496 624 Vee
FLAG -496 272 Vcc
FLAG 608 208 Vee
FLAG 608 128 Vcc
FLAG 320 144 0
FLAG 528 464 0
FLAG 192 512 0
FLAG 192 288 Vo1
FLAG -320 272 0
FLAG 496 288 Vc1
FLAG 912 160 Vo2
FLAG -64 240 Vee
FLAG -64 320 Vcc
SYMBOL voltage -496 304 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 13
SYMBOL voltage -496 480 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value 13
SYMBOL res 704 0 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res 480 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL res 704 272 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL cap 512 368 R0
WINDOW 39 24 84 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 0.5nF
SYMATTR SpiceLine IC=0
SYMBOL res 368 272 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res 64 128 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res -192 256 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMATTR SpiceLine tol=1 pwr=0.1
SYMBOL res 144 272 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 5.1k
SYMBOL zener 208 400 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value PTZ6_8B
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL zener 176 432 R0
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value PTZ6_8B
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL Opamps\\LT1056 -64 352 M180
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL Opamps\\LT1056 608 96 R0
SYMATTR InstName U2
TEXT -344 736 Left 2 ;Descrption: Bistable multivibrator circuit\nVersion: 0.1
TEXT -322 808 Left 2 !.tran 1m


Thanks. I changed the op amp to LT1056. The circuit hanged for too long with OP amp OP296.  Now, I get the same signals.

As G36 mentioned, your circuit works if the OpAmps have enough bandwidth.
Using the very fast AD797 with 110 MHz bandwith the resulting frequency is 16.5 kHz, in the simulation from G36 using LT1065 with 5.5 MHz bandwidth the circuit generates around 8 kHz.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab


The frequency generated with LT1056 was about 9 KHz.

@AmitM Jens is trying to say that the opamp you originally chose, the OP269, is way too slow for this circuit.

G36,I also had seen that. Op296 Op07 are slow for this application. Op27 and OP37 are functioning. Thanks for your explanation.

G36, The gain bandwidth product of Op296 was about 450 KHz.The same for OP27- 8 MHz ,for OP37 -63 MHz , for L1056, it was 5.5 MHz.
